# in python picking tuples from two list of tuples if both the list contain common elements

Tags: python, list, tuples, set

I want to make a new list of tuples from tuples of list1 if elements in list1 are present or common in list2.

```
list1 = [('We', 'all'), ('all', 'live'), ('live', 'in'), ('in', 'a'),
         ('a', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'submarine.')]

list2 = [('A', 'live'), ('live', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'submarine'),
         ('submarine', 'lifeform'), ('lifeform', 'in'), ('in', 'a'),
         ('a', 'sea.')]
```

expected output = `[('live', 'in'), ('in', 'a'), ('a', 'yellow')]`

my code is below: It works in this case, but somehow fails in large datasets.

```
All_elements_set1 = set([item for tuple in list1 for item in tuple])

All_elements_set2 = set([item for tuple in list2 for item in tuple])


common_set = All_elements_set1 & All_elements_set2

new_list = [(i,v) for i,v in list1 if i (in common_set and v in common_set)]

print new_list
```

Comment: Also explain, what does "somehow fails in large datasets" mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

```
In [39]: from itertools import chain

In [40]: list1 = [('We', 'all'), ('all', 'live'), ('live', 'in'), ('in', 'a'),
    ...:          ('a', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'submarine.')]
    ...: 
    ...: list2 = [('A', 'live'), ('live', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'submarine'),
    ...:          ('submarine', 'lifeform'), ('lifeform', 'in'), ('in', 'a'),
    ...:          ('a', 'sea.')]
    ...: 

In [41]: elems = set(chain.from_iterable(list2))

In [42]: [tup for tup in list1 if elems.issuperset(tup)]
Out[42]: [('live', 'in'), ('in', 'a'), ('a', 'yellow')]
```

Comment: +1 nice one.. was difficult to understand from the question what OP wants

Comment: `all(e in elems for e in t)` can be replaced by `elems.issuperset(t)` - it's a lot more efficient (just timed them), and it's more obvious what it does

Comment: @Volatility -- Thanks, thats a nice improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't need to make a set for elements in list1. All you need if check, for each tuple in list1, whether their elements are in some tuple in list 2...

```
list1 = [('We', 'all'), ('all', 'live'), ('live', 'in'), ('in', 'a'),
         ('a', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'submarine.')]

list2 = [('A', 'live'), ('live', 'yellow'), ('yellow', 'submarine'),
         ('submarine', 'lifeform'), ('lifeform', 'in'), ('in', 'a'),
         ('a', 'sea.')]

Elements_set2 = set([item for tuple in list2 for item in tuple])

print [(i,v) for i,v in list1 if (i in Elements_set2 and v in Elements_set2 )]
```

As you are not giving details about the case where your code fails, cannot check whether this one works on your failing example.